# Provide Default Twitter account for authentication

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to display the feeds of one specific twitter page. Regardless of who the user is, I want to be able to specify the number of tweets to get and the twitter user to retrieve for (this will be hardcoded)

I have used the following code to start the authentication

self.accountStore = store;
    ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [self.accountStore
                                         accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                                         ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

There is a lot of code below this, which I follow from the twitter documentation, so basically, this will throw a UIAlertView if no accounts are set up.

I want to take into account the fact that, the users of this app:
1 - might not have a twitter account
2 - they do not use twitter on their phone and so its not set up in settings

The twitter feed serves as a news feed in this application, so my question is,

Is there anyway, I can provide the twitter api a default user, hardcoded, without having to go through the accounts ?

I want to know what sort of info the accountStore is pulling, so perhaps I could replicate it and send it to the twitter api after building a similar structure.

I am a bit new to iPhone programming so forgive me if some of this is very obvious.

Thank You for your time.

Comment: Are you just trying to get a specific user's twitter feed? Because if so, you do not have to necessarily go through a whole bunch of authentification. You can do it all through the Twitter web API

Comment: Yes .. I just want one specific twitter feed, can you please point me to a tutorial or a link ... Thank You for your time.

Comment: Sorry it took a while for my response. I will post an answer below shortly

Comment: Actually it may take a little more time because it looks like they deprecated api version 1.0. So yeah I will have to re-figure this out

Comment: I will likely not have a response for this for a while, if ever when it comes to twitter, mainly because it seems like they are now making it that you need authorization to view any twitter feeds etc. Meaning you would need a user account. What I have done that may still work is use Tumblr, which I will post below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer which helps me for my requirements,

My requirements were that I was developing an iPhone app and needed specific tweets from one particular user on twitter. While this was very easy using the old twitter api, using v1.1, user authentication was needed.

While iOS provides their own social sdk, I wanted to consider the fact that users might not have twitter or not be signed in on their phones and still receive feeds. From my research, I did not find anything as almost all solutions resulted in checking the iPhone settings of the user to make sure they have set up a twitter account.

So since these were my constraints, I decided to look at creating a web service using PHP, to authenticate with twitter and pull the tweets that I needed. Encode them into JSON and echo it.

Then from the IOS app, I called this web service and deserialized it and used it how I needed to.

Now some code.

Most of the answer to how to use PHP with the new twitter API can be found here:
https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php. Grab the files from here and you can see the example he gives. I have given a small one below.

Here are some of the steps I needed to use

- Create an app on twitter. Go here https://dev.twitter.com/, log in with your twitter account. Once you are there you need to create an application.
- Grab the files from above and place the TwitterAPIExchange.php on your server
- Create your php file and put the **require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php')**; at the top
- After creating your application, from the dashboard, you will be given some information which you need to authenticate with the twitter api. Use it in your php like so

  $settings = array(
      'oauth_access_token' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN",
      'oauth_access_token_secret' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET",
      'consumer_key' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",
      'consumer_secret' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  );

Once you have set this array up you can move onto to specify what you need to set up the things you require

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
$getfields = '?screen_name=screen_name_you_want&count=number_of_tweets_you_want';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
```

The url states the resource I want to get after my script authenticates. Below that are the parameters. The screen name and number of tweets you want to retrieve. The request method protocol will be GET. If you want to post something to a timeline, you will need to use POST but also modify your apps access from your dev account. Currently, my app only has read access as I only needed that.

Then its time to execute

```
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings); 
$tweets = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();
```

If you see the example on github from J7mbo, he echoes the whole timeline, you can do that to see what it looks like, so I wanted to dive deeper and just get the tweets.

```
$tweet_array = array();
$index = 1;
foreach($tweets as $feed=>$item)
{
   $arr_index = 'tweet'.$index;
   $tweet_array[$arr_index] => $item['text'];
   $index++;
}

echo json_encode($arr_index);
```

This will echo json like "tweet1"=>"Latest Tweet","tweet2"=>"Second Latest Tweet"

From Xcode then you can call this url and get the json feeds and use it how you want.

On a side note: whenever the script is run, it takes a while to do the authentication and retrieve the feeds and since this was targeting an IOS app, it might be best to apply caching. Depending on how often the user in question updates their twitter, you can have a time_limit. Whenever you retrieve tweets store it in the database. If the next user requests for tweets, check the time limit, if it is less, then retrieve it from your db, if it has passed the time limit, update your database and send the user new results.

I would like to thank J7mbo for his GitHub library, and also MZimmerman as he points out a much easier workaround to this using tumblr.

Thanks.

Comment: Good solution. I have definitely done something like this before. Sometimes it makes things so much easier. Just be careful because if you end up with a lot of users, this can get bogged down, but it will work until that point. One thing I may suggest is that your webserver periodically checks twitter and stores tweets in MySQL or something so that you are not pinging twitter with each phone request and you exceed your API limit. Best of luck, and thanks for being a new user that actually knows how to use this website

Comment: Hello MZimmerman, I actually have a last update variable in my database. These guys update their twitter like maybe once every 2 hours on average. So if the user comes in within the update time limit (2 hours) I have set, they only get the tweets stored locally. If its beyond that, I request new tweets, I download new tweets.

Although, you have mentioned an important point of the API limit so perhaps a script could be set up as part of a CRON job to run periodically and this way the api ALWAYS takes tweets from the database as it is automatically updated every 2 hours.

Comment: Continued .. I am not a server expert and I did think of what happens if the userbase becomes large, which I do not forsee for a long time, although a question is what should I do then ?

To handle more users, does the server have to be upgraded to provide greater bandwidth to process several request ?

Thank You for your time.

Comment: Yes, you would likely need to look into a server service, such as Amazon EC2, or something similar that has distributable servers, and massive bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter I believe will actually make this harder right now because they require authorization to be able to get information such as tweets and so on. However, Tumblr does not require authorization. So what you can do is post any updates that you would have posted via Twitter, on Tumblr.

You can then simply access this information with the Tumblr web API with a simple URL, like as follows

http://username.tumblr.com/api/read/json?num=25

This will return a feed of length 25 that you can then parse using `NSJSONSerialization` to get it into an NSDictionary format, which will be easy to process however you want to.

Comment: Hi MZimmerman, thanks for taking the time to answer. Yes the problem is the change in the api and the authentication required. Actually, authenticating is not a problem, I just want to know how can I provide the values such as user name and password and keep this as default because I doubt the guys who I am building the app for will be open to using tumblr.

Comment: Maybe I am unsure about what you want then. Do you need any random person to be able to view a specific feed? And you want to say pre-load the app with say your credentials so they can view the information/pass authentication.

Comment: Hello MZimmerman, Yes ... exactly. Say you use the app, you don't have twitter set up on your phone, but you can still view the feeds of the specific twitter feed. 

I can also use the app and say I have an account set up on my phone but still it uses the hardcoded credentials to authenticate and show me the same feeds you are viewing as well. 

Regardless of the user, all the app users see the same set of feeds.

Comment: Thank You MZimmerman for your time, I have found a solution for my issue.